# How does this partial differentiation work?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Good day,

There was a partial derivative in the lecture today that I can't comprehend. Can someone please explain how this works? Maybe there is a rule that I'm not thinking of right now.

It's about the Cauchy problem in a quasilinear PDE second order for independent variables $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$. Further let $\eta \in I \subset \mathbb{R}$.
Let $$n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x'(\eta)+y'(\eta)}} \binom{-y'(\eta)}{x'(\eta)}$$ 
Then $$ \frac{\partial u(x(\eta),y(\eta))}{\partial n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x'(\eta)+y'(\eta)}} \left(-y'(\eta)\frac{\partial u(x(\eta),y(\eta))}{\partial x}+x'(\eta) \frac{\partial u(x(\eta),y(\eta))}{\partial y}\right) $$

But why? It seems the derivate is just $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}=<n,\nabla u>$$
Is this a kind of rule? Doesn't look like chain rule to me.

Thanks a lot,

Marvin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\nu=(\nu_1,\nu_2)$ be a **unit vector**, then the directional derivative of $u$ with respect to $\nu$ is defined by 
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}=\nu\cdot\nabla u = \nu_1 u_x + \nu_2 u_y$$

Let now compute the unit normal vector of the curve $r(t) = (x(t),y(t))$.
The unit tangent vector  to $n$ is given by $T=\frac{r'(t)}{\|r'(t)\|}=\frac{(x'(t),y'(t))}{\sqrt{x'(t)^2+y'(t)^2}}$
Therefore, $$n=\frac{T'}{\|T\|}.$$
It can be proven that 
$$n=\frac{(-y'(t),x'(t))}{\sqrt{x'(t)^2+y'(t)^2}}$$
you can verify that this new definition of $n$ is orthogonal to $T$ by evaluation $n\cdot T=0$.

Substitute this to formula of $\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}$ to get the formula you have seen in the class.

Comment: Ahh, thank you, I didn't know that the directional derivative with a unit vector is defined like this. Thank you.